# How to save same ODT file with different styles in libre office writer

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, styles

I have this odt document. I need to save it with two different styles. One for reading (which includes sans font, bigger size ..) and one for printing(with smaller serif font). I created two templates with the required styles. Is there any way to apply these styles to existing document(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a document, go to *Styles > Load Styles* and specify *Overwrite*. Then choose the template.

https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/swriter/guide/load_styles.html